# How to organise internationalizing a Netbeans/Glasshfish project

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, glassfish-4

I've got an existing Netbeans/Glassfish web application that was created automatically using one of the Netbeans wizards.

The project structure has

```
/src
    /conf
    /java/com/java source here
/web
    /WEB-INF
    /css
    /img
    etc
```

I'm not looking to i18n the project, replacing the hard coded strings with messages from a properties file.

The actual process of performing the translations and placing them into the JSP seems straightforwards enough - but what I don't understand is where I should place the properties file containing the translations.

The best place I can think of is inside /web/WEB-INF but I'm not sure that that is the right place and Google has failed me. Is WEB-INF the correct place for the translations files to go?

Comment: Put them in the classpath.

Comment: @Stefan Can you be more specific?

Comment: They should be in `WEB-INF/classes` (or a sub directory thereof), which means they'll be in the classpath, as well as accessible to the different resource/messagebundle frameworks.

Comment: Ok, I have no WEB-INF/classes folder but I can add one easily enough.

Comment: The classes folder is automatically generated when you compile...

Comment: Put them in src/main/resources.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help in the comments.

I created `messages.properties` in the default package

I added

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

to dispatcher-servlet.xml

I added

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
```

To the top of the jsp file and then.

```
    <title><spring:message code="login.title" /></title>
```

Correctly showed the page with the translated title.